# Start time of a process running on remote machine using powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to get the start time of a process running on remote machine using powershell.
On my local computer I get it simply by using `get-process $processname | select StartTime`.

I tried using `get-process $processname -computername $server1 | select StartTime` but this is returning me nothing.

Please suggest any better way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using  `WMI`. This  code return start time of powershell.exe process:

```
$a =  gwmi win32_process -computername $server1| ? { $_.name -eq "powershell.exe" }

$a | % { $_.ConvertToDateTime( $_.CreationDate )}
```

Comment: This may not work if $a contains more than one process. I suggest you pipe to foreach-object

Comment: ok thats pretty cool..now I want to format it in my desired way like 5/15/2012 12:35:16 PM ..but no format mechanism is working that I used with get-date command..Can you help me in that?

Comment: Hey christian it worked thanks..but still its not giving the time in am/pm...Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Abhi_Mishra try `$a | % { $_.ConvertToDateTime( $_.CreationDate ) } | Get-Date -format "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"`

Comment: Wow thats the best way,It solved my some other problems as well..Tons of thanks..:)

Answer (score 3):

```
PS> $StartTime= @{n='StartTime';e={$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.CreationDate)}}
PS> gwmi win32_process -cn $server1 -filter "Name='$processname' AND CreationDate IS NOT NULL" | select Name,$StartTime
```

Comment: Better answer, IMHO, as it more easily adds other fields.